# How to scrape the Term of Office dates only that follow a span?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

I am trying to scrape the Terms of office and display the years in a dataframe. But unable to scrape the data.

I am trying this code, but only getting the Term of Office text instead of years

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

president_name = soup.find_all('div', class_='presidentListing')
term_of_office = soup.find_all('span', class_='terms')


president_name = soup.find_all('div', class_='presidentListing')
term_of_office = soup.find_all('span', class_='terms')

names = []
terms = []

for i in president_name:
    name = i.text.split('(')[0].strip()
    if name != '':
        names.append(name)
        
for i in term_of_office:
    term = i.text
    terms.append(term)           
    
terms
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `next_sibling` to select the term after the `span` and should also change your strategy selecting and processing the HTML elements:

```
... 
data = []

for e in soup.select('li:has(h3)'):
    data.append({
        'name':e.h3.text, 
        'term':e.span.next_sibling
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output

|  | name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Shri Ram Nath Kovind (birth - 1945) | 25 July, 2017 to 25 July, 2022 |
| 1 | Shri Pranab Mukherjee (1935-2020) | 25 July, 2012 to 25 July, 2017 |
| 2 | Smt Pratibha Devisingh Patil (birth - 1934) | 25 July, 2007 to 25 July, 2012 |
| ... |  |  |
| 12 | Dr. Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan (1888-1975) | 13 May, 1962 to 13 May, 1967 |
| 13 | Dr. Rajendra Prasad (1884-1963) | 26 January, 1950 to 13 May, 1962 |